# How to output additional debugging information using Eclipse and Android JUnit

Tags: android, eclipse, junit

I am developing a simple android application using eclipse.  I wrote a JUnit TestCase for a class I wrote.  One particular test compares two 2d arrays so see if they are equal.  If they are not equal the test fails.  When the test fails I would like to print out the contents of the offending array to see what went wrong. I have tried System.out.print and it doesn't show up in the console or JUnit results.  What am I doing wrong?  Is it even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Log](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html) to write to the LogCat window in Eclipse.

ETA: [Screenshot](https://sites.google.com/site/eldarerathis/uploads/log.png) of the LogCat window in Eclipse with some logging code highlighted.

Comment: Thanks, I couldn't get it to print in eclipse for some reason, but in the shell I ran adb logcat Class:V *:S and it work works perfect.